# How to get grails array in angular

Tags: html, angularjs, json, grails

I have the following controller in grails

```
package tabla
class TablaController {

def search() {
    def  v = Vendedor.list()
    [vendedor:v]
}}
```

and I sent data to view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">   </script>

<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="x='${vendedor.firstName}'" >

<table>

<th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th>
<tr ng-repeat="first in x track by $index ">
    <td ng-bind="first"></td>
    <!--<td ng-bind="y"></td>-->
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

but I get printed in vertical way for obvious reasons character by character
[
L
u
i
s
,
p
e
d
r
o
,
g
e
r
a
r
d
o
,
a
l
f
o
n
s
o
,
i
s
r
a
e
l
,
a
l
e
j
a
n
d
r
o
,
y
o
n
a
t
a
n
]

is there a way to fix it? I assume it gotta be something about the parse

Comment: provide the code of your angular controller

Comment: it has no controller..... I get the info that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular requires its data as JSON. You need to convert your vendedor-data into a JSON array.

Try this:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init='x=${vendedor*.firstName as grails.converters.JSON}' >
```

Comment: Worked pretty well